# html symbols are getting replaced by ascii codes in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, analytics

I  am having a php string in the following format:

```
<pre>
$configOptions = "vCPUCores : '1 vCPU $3.00AUD',Ram : '0.5 GB $10.00AUD',PrimaryDrive : '50GB',DriveIOPs : '100'";
</pre>
```

I need to pass this string to analytics using javascript.

```
  <script>
           var configOptions = <?php echo $configOptions; ?>;
    </scrip>
```

However, when the data is passed to analytics, the single quotes are replaced by the corresponding ascii  codes -&#039;

The output is obtained in the following format:

```
   var configOptions = vCPUCores : '1 vCPU3.00AUD',Ram : '0.5 GB10.00AUD',PrimaryDrive : \'50GB\'
```

Here all the single quotes have got replaced ( when viewed through the browser source). This doesn't occur if I print the same in php. The issue occurs when the php data is passed to javascript.

I have tried several javascript and php encoding techniques regarding this, But none of them work.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using JSON?

Comment: I have tried using json_encode. But it didnt work

Comment: Why is your config a string? You need a data structure. Use an associative array in PHP that will map to an object in JavaScript.

Comment: I have also tried htmlentities. But it's not working

Comment: have u tried  urlencode as sending http request thus it generally works

Comment: @Vineeth, That's not woking :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
       var configOptions = <?php echo urlencode($configOptions); ?>;
</scrip>
```

or

```
<script>
       var configOptions = <?php echo rawurlencode($configOptions); ?>;
</scrip>
```

Comment: Ther aren't working. I am not getting the correct output with single quotes. If I use the above methods, I only get the following output. <pre>                                                                 configOptions = vCPUCores+%3A+%26%23039%3B1+vCPU3.00AUD%26%23039%3B%2CRam+%3A+%26%23039%3B0.5+GB10.00AUD% </pre>

Comment: yes it is correct as you have to send this string to analysis and they will decode it and correct output would be published.

Comment: I 100% sure they will and if not then ask analysis website to solve issue